# constructor cannot be applied to given types ? actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, spring-boot

**I have the following java Model class :**

```
@Data
public class Modality {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String name;
    private String typemod;
    private Float typem;
    private Float tempspl;
    private String typemodeti;
    private String preparation;
    private String comment;
}
```

**I have the following Entity class :**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_Modality")
public class ModalityEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "bigint(20)")
    private BigInteger id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "typec")
    private String typec;

    @Column(name = "typedim")
    private Float typedim;
    @Column(name = "tempspl")
    private Float tempspl;
    @Column(name = "preparation")
    private String preparation;

    @Column(name = "typemod")
    private String typemod;

    @Column(name= "comment")
    private String comment;
}
```

**I have the following java class :**

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    StandardPlanServiceImpl standardplanDao;
    @Autowired
    ModalityServiceImpl modalityDao;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() throws Exception {

        log.error("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));        
        List<StandardPlan> list = standardplanDao.getAllStandardPlan();
        List<Modality> modalityList = modalityDao.getAllModality();

        for(StandardPlan plan : list) {
            log.error("Plan : " + plan.getType());
        }
        for(Modality modaList : modalityList){
            log.error("Modality List :"+modaList.getComment());
        }

        modalityDao.save(newModality("testName", "Moyenne", 6.F, 4.F, "OUI", "OUI", "TestComment"));

        modalityDao.getAllModality().forEach(c-> {
            System.out.println(c.getName());
        });
    }
}
```

**And when i compile i got this error in docker console:**

> constructor Modality in class App.Test.model.Modality cannot be applied to given types;
>    [ERROR]   required: no arguments
>    [ERROR]   found: java.lang.String,java.lang.String,float,float,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
>    [ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see the exact line where the exception occurs, but from error log it is obvious that you are trying to do;

```
new Modality("testName", "Moyenne", 6.F, 4.F, "OUI", "OUI", "TestComment")
```

for it matches the arg type list in the error;

```
String, String, float, float, String, String, String
```

It is due to absence of any such constructor in your `Modality` class definition. `@Data` will give you only a no-args-constructor that is `new Modality()`. You need to add a custom constructor as following to suit your needs;

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Modality {

    private BigInteger id;
    private String name;
    private String typecompmod;
    private Float typedim;
    private Float tempsplaytex;
    private String typemodetiqu;
    private String preparation;
    private String comment;

    // this custom constructor is what you need
    public Modality(String name, String typecompmod, Float typedim, Float tempsplaytex, String typemodetiqu, String preparation, String comment) {
        this.name = name;
        this.typecompmod = typecompmod;
        this.typedim = typedim;
        this.tempsplaytex = tempsplaytex;
        this.typemodetiqu = typemodetiqu;
        this.preparation = preparation;
        this.comment = comment;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error happenning here: 
        
modalityDao.save(newModality("testName","Moyenne",6.F,4.F,"OUI","OUI","TestComment"));

Because if delete the operation for posting , i compile successfully and i get the names of my modalities

Comment: @benkhaledSaddam please try adding that custom constructor in the `Modality` class, then try again!

Comment: @ buræquete I did and i got another compilation failure: calss,interface, or enum expected.

Comment: @benkhaledSaddam that means you have extra curly brackets somewhere maybe `{` or `}`, you have a lot of very basic issues...